# Table cells have no height when they have the attribute contentEditable, but no data in the cell

Tags: html, html-table, contenteditable

I have an html table that autosizes.  The table has an extra row at the bottom with its  elements containing the contentEditable="true" attribute.

When none of the cells in the row of contentEditable="true" cells have any value, the row has almost no height.  Conversely, if any cell in the row of contentEditable="true" cells has any value, then all of the cells in that row display with the height of the rows above it.

Here's the fiddle that shows my issue.  http://jsfiddle.net/bjsfiddle/4mVgg/ 
The first table below has a "." character in the first cell that has the contentEditable="true" set.  This row displays properly:

```
<h4>Table where last line can be edited</h4>
<h5>(the contenteditable row has a "." in the name field</h5>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Address</th>
  <th>Telephone</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Billy Byte</td>
  <td>999 MyStreet</td>
  <td>555 777 8558</td>
</tr>
<tfoot>
    <td contenteditable="true"><div>.</div></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"><div></div></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"><div></div></td>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

The second table below does not have the "." character in any contentEditable field, and the height
of that table row is extremely small.  See below:

```
<h4>Same Table, no "." in the Name field</h4>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Address</th>
  <th>Telephone</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Billy Byte</td>
  <td>999 MyStreet</td>
  <td>555 777 8558</td>
</tr>
<tfoot>
    <td contenteditable="true"><div></div></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"><div></div></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"><div></div></td>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

I'm sure it's probably something simple, but I just can't seem to find the answer.
Thanks much for any help

Comment: thanks.  That works pretty well.  Is there a relatively easy way to dynamically base the td height off of the previous rows, if those rows don't have a height specification?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

you can do a min-height, that way if it's empty, it will at least show the min height.

Use 20px or however many pixels you want!

so if you have CSS file, you can just throw this in there

```
td { 
   min-height: 20px;
}
```

if no CSS file, just add style tags in between the head tags in your html like this

```
<style type="text/css">
td { min-height: 20px; }
</style>
```

Comment: Hmm.  It doesn't seem to work for me, whereas your last suggestion did.  I wonder what I'm doing wrong.  I copied the above into the the jsfiddle css section, but it didn't change the height.  (Your first suggestion does).